# many to many relationships tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

- students:
  studentid
  ,
  first name
  ,
  last name ,
  major ,
  schoolyear
  ,
- courses:
  studentid,
  courseid
  ,
  coursename
  ,
  department
  ,
- students_courses: 
  firstname
  ,
  studentid
  ,
  courseid
  ,

I need to write a SQL Query that shows which students are taking which courses One student should be able to register for more than one course and One course should be able to be taken by more than one student.

The query I created but I am getting an error, can someone help.

```
 select

 students.firstname as 'name',
 GROUP_CONCAT(courses.coursename) as 'course name'

 from students
 join students_courses on students.studentid = students_courses.studentid

 join courses on courses.courseid = students_courses.Courseid

 group by students.Firstname

 order by courses.coursename
```

Comment: First: why do you use group concat? 2 what is the error you get?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I am sorry for that. the query is not running how it should

Answer (score 0):

Your tables structure seems to me wrong.

Table students: ok
Table courses: remove student_id
Table student_courses: remove student_name

Then query the data in this way

```
SELECT * FROM students AS s LEFT JOIN student_courses AS sc ON s.id=sc.student_id LEFT JOIN courses AS c ON c.id=sc.course_id
```

Add the necessary WHERE clauses if needed.

The query show all the courses taken by all the users. It also print users without courses.

Comment: Hi, Can you please help I am new with mysql and writing queries. I put in the info you gave me and it says clause is ambiguous

Comment: You do not have to write "WHERE clause", but depending on what you want to show "WHERE student_id=variable" or "WHERE course_id=variable" and variable is of course the ID of the resource you are trying to fetch and you are interested jn.

Comment: I have to write the query and I am getting an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, I know but I run the program before add the "where clause" and i get the error that I told u "clause is ambiguous'

Comment: Did you fix the query using your table field name?

Comment: Did you fix your table structure? Could you update the question with the up-to date tables?